# The current operation requires a safe (isolated) Vert.x sub-context,

Tags: command-line, quarkus, quarkus-reactive, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

I am trying to run a reactive method from QuarkusMain method and get the above error.

- I use quarkus 2.16.0.Final
- My intention is to run this application as a task when required. Alternatively schedule it as a CronJob on kubernetes or standalone. For this reason I do not want to introduce @Scheduled annotation.
- My application will compile as uber-jar and will be dockerized and run on different targets

My main class looks something like this

```java
@QuarkusMain
public class Main implements QuarkusApplication {

    @Inject
    io.quarkus.mailer.reactive.ReactiveMailer mailer;

    @Inject
    AggregationHandler aggregationHandler;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Quarkus.run(Main.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
         aggregationHandler.aggregate()
            .onSubscription().invoke(this::logStarted) // logs status at start
            .onFailure().invoke(this::logFailure)      // logs status on error. Calls Quarkus.asyncExit();
            .subscribe().with(i -> logSuccess());      // logs status on completion. Calls Quarkus.asyncExit();

        Quarkus.waitForExit();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The aggregation class looks like below

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class AggregationHandler {

    @Inject
    AggregationService aggregationService;

    public Uni<Void> aggregate() {
        return Uni.createFrom().voidItem()
            // stages below call other reactive methods
            .onItem().call(i -> aggregationService.download_item_1())
            .onItem().call(i -> aggregationService.download_item_2())
            .onItem().call(i -> aggregationService.download_item_3())
            .onItem().call(i -> aggregationService.download_item_4());
    }
}
```

**Edit1:** Some more context on the problem. The methods `download_item_1() ...` use reactive-rest-client to fetch data from a source and then save the data to database using hibernate-reactive.

The `download_item_1()` method calls a repository, which looks like

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class AccProdRepository {
    @Inject
    Mutiny.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   
    public Uni<Void> mergeCategories() {
        return sessionFactory
            .withTransaction(s -> s.createNativeQuery(SQLConstant.MERGE_CATEGORIES).executeUpdate())
            .onItem().transformToUni(i -> Uni.createFrom().voidItem());
    }
}
```

This used to work before, when I had `@Scheduled` annotation on the `aggregate()` method. But then after some consultation within the team, we changed the design to trigger the aggregation using the main method. Since then, we get the below stacktrace.

```
2024-01-12 10:59:54,572 ERROR [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-4) Mutiny had to drop the following exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The curre
nt operation requires a safe (isolated) Vert.x sub-context, but the current context hasn't been flagged as such. You can still use Hibernate Reactive, you just need to avoid using th
e methods which implicitly require accessing the stateful context, such as MutinySessionFactory#withTransaction and #withSession.
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.context.VertxContextSafetyToggle.checkIsSafe(VertxContextSafetyToggle.java:89)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.context.VertxContextSafetyToggle.validateContextIfExists(VertxContextSafetyToggle.java:72)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.customized.CheckingVertxContext.get(CheckingVertxContext.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionFactoryImpl.withSession(MutinySessionFactoryImpl.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionFactoryImpl.withTransaction(MutinySessionFactoryImpl.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny$SessionFactory.withTransaction(Mutiny.java:1877)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.ReactiveSessionFactoryProducer_ProducerMethod_mutinySessionFactory_f400be8ad6884ffa846bcddd4116ae0c9f200ae3_ClientProxy.withTransaction(
Unknown Source)
        at xxx.xxx.support.aggregation.repository.AccProdRepository.mergeCategories(AccProdRepository.java:39)
```

**Edit 2** : I can confirm now, if I drop the approach of using the main method and re-enable the `@Scheduled` annotation, the aggregation works just fine as before. I feel that there is some disconnect in my understanding of how to call a reactive method inside QuarkusMain, which prepares the vertx context in a different way. But I could be wrong

Comment: From reading the question I don't understand what problem you are facing. Can you enhance the question please?